# Get Node from Coordinates (long, lat) in Open street maps

Tags: openstreetmap, osrm

Using OSRM API, I found the coordinates of the intersections along a route.

I want to know what are the corresponding node IDs.
Is there any API to find the node IDS from the coordinate points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any API to find the node IDS from the coordinate points?

Yes. You need to pass [`annotations=nodes`](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/blob/master/docs/http.md#route-service) as additional query parameter. `routes[i].legs[j].annotations.nodes` will be an array of OSM IDs that you can use to link the data with OSM.

Linking this to the coordinates in the step is a little bit complicated: You would need to concatenate all `RouteStep.geometry` and remove the duplicated coordinates (`steps[i].geometry[-1] == steps[i+1].geometry[0]`).

Comment: In OSRM annotations = true/false only. 
nodes is not an option available. Are you implying another API?

Comment: From API 5.6 onward - http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.7.0/api/?language=cURL#route-service